# Print PDF Generated by jsPDF in Desktop and Mobile Devices Both

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, jspdf

I have an `angular 10` application. In which on click of a button a `mat-dialog` is opened. Inside this `mat-dialog` I have a table that contains brief data of user's orders. And there is a column in that table with title **Actions**. In this actions column you can download and print the data related to that particular order.

Here's the code for the orders table:

**order.component.html**

```html
<table mat-table class="tableclass noBottom" [dataSource]="orderDetails">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="First Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">
            {{ 'orderDialog.first_name' | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.FirstName }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Middle Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">
            {{ 'orderDialog.middleName' | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.MiddleName }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Last Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">
            {{ 'orderDialog.last_name' | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.LastName }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Date of Birth">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">{{ 'orderDialog.dob' | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.DateofBirth }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Order Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">
            {{ 'orderDialog.order_name' | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.orderName }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Order ID">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">
            {{ 'orderDialog.orderID' | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.orderID }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-head">{{ 'orderDialog.actions' | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell class="tablecontent" *matCellDef="let element">
            <div class="orderActions">
                <p (click)="downloadOrderInfo(element)">
                    <mat-icon class="edit-icon">file_download</mat-icon>
                </p>
                <p (click)="printOrderInfo(element)">
                    <mat-icon class="edit-icon">print</mat-icon>
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

My use case is to show few details about order, and when user clicks on download or print, I generate a PDF containing all the info related to that order. To generate this PDF I'm using `jsPDF`. I'll not be including the PDF generation utility as it's quiet big and irrelevant to include.

For printing the PDF, I followed the following approach using `jsPDF's autoPrint()` function:

```js
this.orderDoc= generatePDF(this.orderDetails);
this.orderDoc.autoPrint();
this.orderDoc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

It works absolutely fine in desktop but instead of printing the PDF it downloads it in Mobile devices.

Here's another approach that I tried to print the PDF:

```js
this.orderDoc= generatePDF(this.orderDetails);
var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(this.orderDoc.output('blob'));
let newWindow = window.open(pdfUrl, "_blank");
newWindow.print();
```

This approach also fails in mobile devices and work great in desktop devices. It has the same behaviour as the above one.

So, is there anyway I can print the PDF created by `jsPDF` in both Desktop devices and Mobile devices??